# Drawing oval in canvas using swing

Tags: java, swing, canvas, graphics, awt

I am new to Java and I have a problem with drawing an oval using paintComponent method. I found many similar threads, but none of the soultions worked. My code:

## RacerMain.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RacerMain {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        //MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jframe.setSize(480,640);
        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jpanel.add(new Dot());
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

## Dot.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dot extends JComponent{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Why it does not work and how to get this code working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` which respects preferred sizes but the default size of the `Dot` component is too small to be seen. You need to use a layout manager that uses the maximum area available or override `getPreferredSize`. Remember to call `pack` before calling `JFrame#setVisible`

```
jpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can set preferred size in constructor:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dot extends JComponent {
    public Dot() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 640));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
    }
}
```